# Exclude test dependencies from resolving in SBT

Tags: scala, build, sbt

We have a build.sbt file. I include some libraries:

```
    libraryDependencies +== Seq(
            "xyz" %% "xyz-commons" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
            "abc" %% "abc-commons" % "1.0" % Test
    )
```

Problem: if I execute 'sbt run' all library dependencies are resolved. How can I change this behavior? To circumvent I do the following but it's not optimal:

```
    libraryDependencies ++= (
      if (sys.env.getOrElse("INCLUDE_TEST_LIBS", "false") == "true")
         Seq("abc" %% "abc-commons" % "1.0" % Test)
      else
        Nil
     )
```

I've specified a custom task, let's call the task demo. Basically I want to resolve some libraries only for this specific task. I've found this [1] article with a possible solution but I was unable to map this approach to taskKey.

[1] http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/libraryDependencies-configuration-is-different-for-sbt-assembly-vs-sbt-run-td565.html

Comment: why you don't want test dependency to be resolved while you running app?

Comment: Resolving libraries is not free (space/time).

Comment: @user2129340 Once a library is resolved, it will be cached and will no longer significantly impact performance. If you're looking to use _git_ to distribute your code and _sbt_ to run it, that's not exactly efficient in space/time either - you'd be better off building an installer and just running the resulting application without the _sbt_ baggage. But distributing an app without testing it first makes no sense either.

Comment: @user2129340 - it's more expensive(time/time) to find out that your application does not work only in runtime, while you have tests to run. It's recommended to run them with each introduced changes. ... afterwards you're looking to build a package and run application standalone without SBT.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The scenarios you describe are not applicable to our architecture and scale. Anyway, if someone cares to address the question at hand that 'd be great. In the meanwhile I'll look into sbt for more details.